# Python Errno 13 Permission denied: '/Applications/Python 3.11'

Tags: python

I get the following result while trying to run a small test program in sublime text

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Applications/Python 3.11'
[cmd: ['/Applications/Python 3.11', '-u', '/Users/User/Desktop/python_work/test_2.py']]
[dir: /Users/User/Desktop/python_work]
[path:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/laps:/Applications/LittleSnitch.app/Contents/Components:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin]
[Finished]
```

the Code I ran was following:

```
string1 = 'hi'
string2 = 'hello'
string3 = string1 + string2
print (string3)
```

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Another file also had the same issue, but that issue got resolved by changing the folder name which contained the file as both the folder and the file were named the same. For the this test2.py the folder name is different, hence I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is some permissions issue. You are really going to have to provide more details, although maybe some sublime text user will know. Can  you just run the program from the terminal?

Comment: Or better yet, since recently Mac OS did funny things with permissions in Desktop etc, consider just not using that directory and putting your file in another directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially a guess, but:

You have *probably* told Sublime Text that your Python executable is `/Applications/Python 3.11`. However, that’s usually a folder containing some auxiliary GUI apps, not the actual Python executable. Judging by your PATH value, the correct thing to say should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3`.